# Typeerror: "dict is not callable"

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm working on a marry command according to my discord bot. Everything seemed fine, the "*status* command displays what i want, but i'm not able to update it once someone married. It gives me this error:
"line 70, in update_status
users(user)[mode] = change
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

This is my code:

```
import discord
import datetime
import json
import os
from discord.ext import commands

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\jerem\\Pycharmprojects\\test")

class marriage(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def marry(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
        user = ctx.author
        await self.open_account(ctx.author)
        await self.open_account(user)
        if member:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Marriage!", description=f"{member.mention} do you want to marry {ctx.author.mention}? [y/n]", color=0x71368a)
            embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author} proposed!", icon_url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
            def check(msg):
                return msg.author == member and msg.channel == ctx.channel and str(msg.content) in ["y", "Y", "n", "N"]
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
            msg2 = str(msg.content).lower()
            if msg2 == "y":
                await ctx.reply("You're officially married now. Congrats!")
                await self.update_status(ctx.author, "status")
                await self.update_status(user, "status")
            elif str(msg.content) == "n":
                await ctx.reply("The marriage got cancelled.")
            else:
                await ctx.reply("You didn't enter a valid option.")
        else:
            await ctx.reply("You need to mention a user to marry!")

    @commands.command()
    async def status(self, ctx):
        user = ctx.author
        await self.open_account(ctx.author)
        users = await self.get_status_data()
        variable = users.keys()
        for i in variable:
            status_m = i
            status = users[status_m]
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Status about {ctx.author}", description=f" Current relationship status between\n**{status}**\n\nMarried since\n**N/A**\n\nMarriage age\n**N/A**", color=0x71368a)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
        embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author}", icon_url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)


    async def open_account(self, user):
        users = await self.get_status_data()
        if str(user) in users:
            return False
        else:
            users[str(user)] = "Not married!"
        with open("marriage.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        return True

    async def get_status_data(self):
        with open("marriage.json", "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        return users

    async def update_status(self, user, change="You're now married!", mode="status"):
        users = await self.get_status_data()
        users(user)[mode] = change
        with open("marriage.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        status = users(user)["status"]
        return status

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(marriage(bot))
```

Comment: `users[user][mode] = ` I would say

Answer (score 0):

here you are returning `users` as a json object in `get_status_users`

```
  async def get_status_data(self):
        with open("marriage.json", "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        return users

    async def update_status(self, user, change="You're now married!", mode="status"):
        users = await self.get_status_data()
        users(user)[mode] = change # change it to users[user][mode] = change
        with open("marriage.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        status = users(user)["status"]
        return status
```

you need to change line 70 to

```
users[user][mode] = change
```

Comment: I changed it, but now i got this error: line 70, in update_status
    users[user][mode] = change
KeyError: <Member id=703671503954378782 name='down bad' discriminator='8487' bot=False nick='down christmas ⛄' guild=<Guild id=897866866557603890 name='LateNight' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=112>>

Comment: yes, it would be easier for people if you can add some of your ```users``` response. I ll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks